# Error: DPI-1047: Cannot locate a 64-bit Oracle Client library in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, oracle, node-modules, node-oracledb

I recently need oracle db connectivity within my **nodejs application**.
There is an official add-on [node-oracledb](https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/) powered by oracle. While integrating this add-on in my nodejs application, I'm having this error:
**Error: DPI-1047: Cannot locate a 64-bit Oracle Client library**

Environment is as follows:

1. Nodejs (v12.16.1)
2. node-oracledb (v4.2.0)

Comment: [node-oracledb 6.0](https://medium.com/@sharad-chandran/usher-in-a-new-era-with-the-node-oracledb-6-0-pure-javascript-thin-driver-e10e2af693b2) can be used without Instant Client so you won't get this error in common cases now.

Answer (score 2):

I found following reasons that could cause this issue.

1. Oracle client library is neither set in the environment path nor in
   the project's directory at the following path (node_modules > oracledb > build > Release).
2. Visual Studio
   Redistributable is not suitable for your Oracle client library.
3. Nodejs arch (32-bit , 64-bit) must be compatible with Oracle Client
   Library and node-oracledb add-on's arch.

   Hope it will help someone in the future. Thanks

Comment: Yes, reading the [node-oracledb installation instructions](https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/INSTALL.html) definitely helps.